# Template function to override std::vector::assign

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a C++ class which contains a member `vector`. I would like to override the `vector` methods so that MyVector can be used like a `std::vector`. However, the `assign` method keeps throwing a compile error:

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct MyVector {
    typedef std::vector<T> vector_type;

    vector_type my_vector;

    template<class It>
    void assign(It first, It last)
    {
        my_vector.assign<It>(first, last);
    }
};
```

The error:

```
myvector.cpp: In member function ‘void MyVector<T>::assign(It, It)’:
myvector.cpp:12:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
my_vector.assign<It>(first, last);
```

This code compiles without the outer template `T`. In other words, by changing the vector type to:

```
typedef std::vector<int> vector_type;
```

will make the compile error go away, but it doesn't serve my needs though.

The code is compiled on Linux (Ubuntu 18) with gcc version 7.4.0:

> gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the keyword [`template`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/template) to tell that `assign` is a template.

```
my_vector.template assign<It>(first, last);
//        ^^^^^^^^
```

BTW: The template parameter of [`std::vector::assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) could be deduced automatically, so you don't need to specify the template argument explicitly in fact. So just

```
my_vector.assign(first, last);
```